# Find number of degrees to rotate?

Tags: java, math, rotation, angle, degrees

I am trying to find a method which will rotate an object to make it face a specified point, however the numbers I am getting don't make much sense and I don't think I understand what the math methods are returning.

Here is my code:

```
public void rotate(double x, double y) {
    rotateRight(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2((x - getX()), (y - getY()))));
}
```

x and y are the specified point and getX() and getY() are the objects current point, so I am trying to find the number of degrees that object has to turn right to be facing the specified point.

Can anyone recommend a reliable way to do this?

Comment: You need to know what way it's facing right now, to know how much it needs to turn. So you need three things (objects coordinates, desired coordinates, and objects current direction)

Comment: If "getX() and getY() are the object's current point" then you know where the object is, but not which way it's facing.

Comment: So if I did know which way the object was facing as well, then how do I work it out?

Comment: I'd suggest calling your method "face" or something like that rather than simply "rotate", which usually suggests just an angle to rotate the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [matrix transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) to do it properly.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out, but it is just what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your naming is a bit confusing, so I'm making some assumptions here.  Your "object" is located at the origin (0,0) and getX() and getY() return the point that the object is currently facing, and you want the object to face a new point.

From here it's simple trig and arithmetic.  First thing is to figure out your current angle:

```
current_angle=atan(getX()/getY())
```

Your new angle will be

```
new_angle=atan(newX/newY)
```

and the angle you need to rotate through is naturally,

```
rotation_angle=new_angle - current_angle
```

Comment: I'm not so sure. Your "current angle" calculation is flawed: You are assuming "this" is facing away from the origin, because getX and getY tell you only the current *location*, not where you are facing. The "current angle" you calculated is the line from the origina through getX,getY, which is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: @Bohemian - my assumption is that the question wording is incorrect and getX/getY are in fact the point where `this` located at the origin in facing.  So after the questioner calls rotate(x,y), a subsequent call to getX() will return the x from that rotate call.  It's the only way the question has a complete answer as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what units you are using. Personally, in radians, i have this function in my snippets.

```
public static double getAngleBetween(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
      return(Math.atan2(y1-y2, x1-x2));
}
```

Which results in the angle (in radians) between any two abstract points.

Answer (score 0):

The angle returned by `Math.atan2()` is absolute. In order to turn it into a relative rotation you first need to know what the current angle is, then you need to subtract the two.